# How to retrieve multiple results ( ids ) in a query

Tags: php, sql, oop

I want to retrieve multiple results but currently only getting one result, here is my current code:

```
$p_user = $prodata->user_id;
$usx = $user->getdb()->query("SELECT `user_one`, `user_two` FROM `friends` WHERE `user_one`= ? OR `user_two`= ? ", array($p_user, $p_user));

$count_frnds = $usx->count();
if(!$usx->count()){
    echo 'error';
}else {
    foreach($usx->results() as $use){
        $use->user_one;
        $use->user_two;
        if($p_user == $use->user_one){
            $can = $use->user_two;
        }else {
            $can = $use->user_one;
        }

     }
}

echo $can; //want multiple results, but only returns one result.
```

Comment: .... aren't you overwriting `$can`?  Also, unless you have some rule about ids (eg, "user_one is always the 'lower' id"), you probably have to check _both_ columns for _both_ input ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clockwork-Muse already points it out. In your foreach loop, you are overwriting your $can with a new value, so that's why you only get the last result in the loop. Try define your $can as an array first.

```
$can = array();

...

foreach($usx->results() as $use){
    if($p_user == $use->user_one){
        $can[] = $use->user_two;
    }else {
        $can[] = $use->user_one;
    }
}

...

var_dump( $can );

// or

echo implode(",", $can);
```